# Alert message before close wondow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a lot of problems to implement an alert message before close de Chrome window. The message its always the same. It dosen't take the message I set it up..
I read a lot and nothing seems to work propertly, Its always the same message.
Any clue?
this is test my code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
          return 'Are you sure?';
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility

Comment: No longer supported, see above link.

Comment: Oh.. and exist another way?

Answer (score 0):

Due to it no longer being supported, one option is to detect mouseout on the document itself. This obviously won't handle if they clicked a link within your website, but you can handle that internally.

This will detect if they move their cursor out of the browser's window for example to click back/forward or type in a different URL.

```js
    exitpopup = function(e){
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input")
            return;
        var vpWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        if(e.clientX >= (vpWidth - 50))
            return;
        if(e.clientY >= 50)
            return;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if(!from){
            alert("Your modal here!");
            document.removeEventListener("mouseout",exitpopup);
        };
    };
  
  document.addEventListener("mouseout",exitpopup);
```